# How To Link Old, Existing Like Button On My Site To A Facebook Company/Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So I've had a like button on my website for a while. How do I get those likes to show up on a Facebook fan/company page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your website's visitors to "Like" your Facebook Page, then the button on your website should contain the link to your Facebook Page. Otherwise, when visitors click on it they "like" your website. See [Facebook documentation on implementing the button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying to avoid having my like count go back to zero as I implemented linking it to a new Facebook fan/business page. Anyway of doing that?